# Groovy GPath find nodes by many conditions

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing, xmlslurper, gpath

Suppose having XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <level0 id="2" t="1">
        <level1 id="lev1id21" att1="2015-05-12" val="121" status="0" year="2015" month="05" />
        <level1 id="lev1id22" att1="2015-06-13" val="132" status="0" year="2015" month="06" />
        <level1 id="lev1id23" att1="2015-07-11" val="113" status="0" year="2015" month="08" />
        <level1 id="lev1id23" att1="2015-07-11" val="114" status="0" year="2015" month="07" />
    </level0>
</data>
```

I have to find `level1` node by conditions (assuming we could have many `level0` siblings):

1. For each `level0` find all 'level1' nodes which have maximal `att1` value (interpreted as `Date` in yyyy-mm-dd)
2. Among those `level1` nodes find one that has maximal value in year and month attributes, interpreted as `int`s.

For given example, I expect node with `val`="113" value to be found.
Since I'm not an expert in **GPath**, please help to find a correct and Groovish solution. Thanks.

Comment: Your expected result does not match your criteria. You want to sort the nodes by `att1`, then by `year`, then by `month`? In that case I would expect a result of `113` given your data.

Comment: @thecodesmith_ Thanks, I updated expected result, you're right, I expect to get 113

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected behavior is a bit unclear, see my comment on the post. However, I'm working off the assumption you want to sort the data by `att1`, then by `year`, then by `month`, and find the max value.

To do it in a Groovy way, I'd extract some helper methods so you can see what is going on:

```
def date = { Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd', it.@att1.toString()) }
def year = { it.@year.toString() }
def month = { it.@month.toString() }
```

Then you can sort the nodes using the "space-ship" operator `<=>` to do comparison, and using the "elvis" operator `?:` to do the next level comparison if the first returns 0 (which happens when the comparison is equal):

```
def nodes = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml).level0.level1

def max = nodes.sort { a, b ->
    date(a) <=> date(b) ?:
            year(a) <=> year(b) ?:
                    month(a) <=> month(b)
} .collect { it.@val } .last()

println max  
// Prints "113", given your data above
```

Answer (score 1):

For now I've found this solution, I'd like to know if there is a more `Groovish` way to do this.

```
def xml='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <level0 id="2" t="1">
        <level1 id="lev1id21" att1="2015-05-12" val="121" status="0" year="2015" month="05" />
        <level1 id="lev1id22" att1="2015-06-13" val="132" status="0" year="2015" month="06" />
        <level1 id="lev1id23" att1="2015-07-11" val="113" status="0" year="2015" month="08" />
        <level1 id="lev1id23" att1="2015-07-11" val="114" status="0" year="2015" month="07" />
    </level0>
</data>'''

def nodes = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml).level0.level1.findAll {level1 ->
    level1.max {lev1->
        Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd',lev1.@att1.toString())
    }
}
.each {level1 ->
    level1.max { lev1 ->
        lev1.@year.toString() as int
    }
}.max {level1 ->
    level1.@month.toString() as int
}.collect()

println "${nodes.count {it}}"

nodes.each { n ->
    println "val = ${n.@val}"
}
```